# ngFor doesn't throw error

Tags: arrays, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to get `ngFor` to iterate through an array. Realized it's not doing anything whatever I type.

```
<p ngFor="let applier of tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants">{{applier}}</p>
```

Which apparently is very wrong doesn't return any errors. Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
<p *ngFor="let applier of tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants">{{applier}}</p>
```

for more info

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html

## Update

try by printing above `*ngFor`

```
{{tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants | json}}
```

by printing this you will get to know that your JSON is available or not

Answer (score 1):

The `*` is missing before `ngFor`. Try this:

`<p *ngFor="let applier of tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants">{{applier}}</p>`

Comment: @NabilGhulam check my answer

Comment: What's the structure of `tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants` ? If it is an array of objects maybe you need to choose a property like `{{ applier.name }}` or reach the whole object to show it as a json `{{ applier | json}}`

Answer (score 1):

It should be,

```
<p *ngFor="let applier of tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants">{{applier}}</p>
```

Comment: can you post what is inside tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants?

Comment: it's not even made, so I thought I'd get some errors

Comment: What does this display {{tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants | json}}?

Answer (score 0):

Missed *

```
<p *ngFor="let applier of tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants">{{applier}}</p>
```

It is a standard maintained by Angular developer team . More details in the **[docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#asterisk)**

Note: *** represents the structural directives.**

Answer (score 0):

`ngFor` is a directive in angular2. you can wrap up your content in a `template` tag and apply the directive to it and you should get the expected error
eg:

```
<template ngFor [ngForOf]="episodes" let-episode>
  <app-for-example [episode]="episode">
    {{episode.title}}
  </app-for-example>
</template>
```

`*ngFor` is a syntactic sugar for this exact directive. Internally, `*ngFor` processed as follows :
1. The tag is wrapped in a `<template>` tag
2. `*ngFor` is then converted in a directive syntax `ngFor` and applied to the `<template>` tag

I guess you must have been referring some example/tutorial and missed this part

Answer (score 0):

I assume your component would looks this, where you have an array associated with the component

```
export class SomeComponent {
    somearray: string[];
}
```

and in your html you can access this array to show a repeating element as follows,

```
<p *ngFor="let applier of somearray">{{applier}}</p>
```

**But in your case I assume that you have deliberately put an invalid array name as follows and expect an error to be thrown at run time**

```
<p *ngFor="let applier of tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants">{{applier}}</p>
```

But in this case angular does not throw an error and that is the normal behavior. When ever you used a variable name like "tempAahsbdkasjbdnpplicants" which is not included in the scope, angular assume it as an 'undefined' value.When you try to iterate over the 'undefined' or 'null' variables using the *ngFor, Angular just simply ignore the iteration without trowing an error.